# The complement $\mathbb{P}_k^2 \setminus C$ of a plane curve $C$ is affine.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to prove this assertion but failed. It seems that the Veronese embedding is used.
Appreciate for any suggestions or hints.

Comment: Using the Veronese embedding corresponding to the degree of the curve you can reduce to the situation of $\mathbb{P}^n$ minus an hyperplane.

Comment: @DanieleA I have proved that $\nu_d(C)=\nu_d(\mathbb{P}_k^2) \cap H$ where $H$ is a hyperplane. But how can I say the complement is affine.

Comment: Well, you know that $\mathbb{P}^n_k\setminus H \cong \mathbb{A}^n_k$  and then you have a closed subset of affine space that is by definition affine.

Comment: @DanieleA Uh..Can you explain in details? That is, how can I get the isomorphism for $\mathbb{P}_k^2 \setminus C$ from $\nu_d(C)=\nu_d(\mathbb{P}_2^k) \cap H$?Thank you very much!

Comment: @DanieleA I think I know, do you mean $\nu_d(\mathbb{P}_k^2 \setminus C) \subset \mathbb{P}_k^n \setminus H$?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I also have posted a full answer below to be more clear

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $C$ is a curve of degree $d$ and consider the Veronese embedding of degree $d$

$$ \nu_d\colon \mathbb{P}^2_k \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^N_k  $$

Then we know that $\nu_d(C)=\nu_d(\mathbb{P}^2_k)\cap H$, where $H\subseteq \mathbb{P}^N_k$ is an hyperplane, so that

$$ \nu_d(\mathbb{P}_k^2 \setminus C)=\nu_d(\mathbb{P}^2_k)\cap(\mathbb{P}^N_k\setminus H)$$

that is closed in $\mathbb{P}^N_k\setminus H$ since $\nu_d(\mathbb{P}^2_k)$ is closed in $\mathbb{P}^N_k$. Now, since $\nu_d$ is an isomorphism with the image, this shows that $\mathbb{P}^2_k\setminus C$ is isomorphic to a closed subset of $\mathbb{P}^N_k\setminus H \cong \mathbb{A}^N_k$ and hence is affine.

Comment: So nice! Thank you, Daniele A! I think I have understood the proof.